# Rhythmbox Audio cd record plugin missing

Tags: sound, plugins

Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit. On standard install, the plugin AudioCD record is not present. I tried to install the plugin from Synaptic and enabled it, but I still have no option to record a playlist to Audio CD.

Brasero works fine with the same files. Tried to uninstall completely and reinstall latest 3.4... still no Audio CD record plugin, which should be included by default... what am I missing?

Comment: Apparently, you are missing an "Audio CD record plugin". Is it not kind of obvious?

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you want to achieve and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them in their entirety in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please [edit] your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Which package(s) *exactly* did you install and how? Did you restart Rhythmbox afterwards? Does the plug-in show up in Rhythmbox' list of available plug-ins?

Comment: Thank you David, first time with RB 3.3 (standard on 16.04) the plugin did show up after install by Synaptic, but did not work. After remove and reinstall RB PPA & program 3.4 the plug in does not show...should I install it manually? Using what?

Comment: ...plugin is installed, and displays as enabled in Tools...it just does not work: no options to write to CD are available...